# Round UP c# TimeSpan to 5 minutes

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deal with Rounding-off TimeSpan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714221/how-to-deal-with-rounding-off-timespan)

Is there a way to easily round a c# TimeSpan (possible containing more than one day) up so that

0 days 23h 59m  becomes 1 days 0 h 0 m?

0 days 23h 47m  becomes 0 days 23 h 50 m?

etc?

Here's what i've come up with so far:

```
int remainder = span2.Minutes % 5;
if (remainder != 0)
{
    span2 = span2.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5 - remainder));
}
```

it seems like a lot of code for something rather simple:( Isn't there some kind of built in c# function I can use to round timespans?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to deal with Rounding-off TimeSpan?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2714221/102112)

Comment: My question was about Rounding UP, not Mathematical rounding.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here it is:

```
var ts = new TimeSpan(23, 47, 00);
ts = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5 * Math.Ceiling(ts.TotalMinutes / 5));
```

Or with a grain of sugar:

```
public static class TimeSpanExtensions
{
    public static TimeSpan RoundTo(this TimeSpan timeSpan, int n)
    {
        return TimeSpan.FromMinutes(n * Math.Ceiling(timeSpan.TotalMinutes / n));
    }
}

ts = ts.RoundTo(5);
```

Comment: Thank you both, I actually went with the "grain of sugar" one:)

Answer (score 3):

```
 static TimeSpan RoundTimeSpan(TimeSpan value)
 {
     return TimeSpan.FromMinutes(System.Math.Ceiling(value.TotalMinutes / 5) * 5);
 }
```