# Random timer between two numbers

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm currently trying to learn C#.
So i have created an project where i want to generate a random number between 1 Hour for example: A random number from 20-21 PM so like 20.23.

Its working but i need to compare it so when they are equal a pop up is coming but the milliseconds are in my way i need to remove them .
Any idea how i can solve this problem ?

So there is what i got so far:

```
namespace Timer
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private static readonly Random rnd = new Random();
    private static int minimum = 20;
    private static int maximum = 21;
    private static double x = rnd.NextDouble() * (maximum - minimum) + minimum;
    private static TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(x);
    public static TimeSpan timeNow = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
    public static TimeSpan diffTime = timeSpan - timeNow;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (diffTime != timeNow) 
        {
            diffTime = timeSpan - timeNow;
            timeNow = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
            LblTimeLeft.Text = diffTime.ToString();
            LblTime.Text = timeNow.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("EQUAL!");

        }
    }
  }
}
```

I hope you can help me.

Thanks !

Comment: just compare `diffTime - timeNow<TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)` or something similar

Comment: @ironstone13 `(diffTime - timeNow).TotalSeconds < 1`

Comment: The current time will likely never *exactly* equal your datetime.  You're better off checking to see if the two times are within X seconds or milliseocnds of each other.

Comment: @Rotem,  `TimeSpan` structure implements the `<` operator, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.op_lessthan(v=vs.110).aspx , the only issue in the expression above is that it should take an absolute value, I agree :-)

Comment: @ironstone13 Of course, I didn't mean to imply your syntax does not work, just offered a slightly more efficient alternative that does not instantiate a new `TimeSpan` each time.

Comment: @Rotem, I completely agree with you, there is no need to allocate the whole structure on the stack, we can get away with a `double Timespan`. (assuming it is not declared as a const somewhere). By the way, what is the size of a `TimeSpan`? `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))` returns 8 which is the same as `double` ;-)

Comment: @ironstone13 and Rotem like this ? 

`if ((diffTime - timeNow).TotalSeconds < 1)
            {
                diffTime = timeSpan - timeNow;
                timeNow = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
                LblTimeLeft.Text = diffTime.ToString();
                LblTime.Text = timeNow.ToString();
            }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
var timeSpanSeconds = Math.Floor(TimeSpan.FromHours(x).TotalSeconds);
var nowSeconds = Math.Floor(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds);
var diffSeconds = timeSpanSeconds - nowSeconds;
```

and then

```
if (diffSeconds != 0 )
```

or use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704818/round-up-c-sharp-timespan-to-5-minutes) to round the timespans.

Comment: You can also you TotalMinutes, if you decide seconds are too granular.

Comment: Thanks @all. I wrote `if (diffSeconds != 0)` and it works ! Thanks !